# Rails ActiveRecord: legacy table without primary key shows nil for result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I've got a Rails app that'll be sitting on top of a legacy database with some ugly tables that I'm having to deal with. One is a `feature_attributes` table related to `features`. Problem is that this `feature_attributes` table doesn't have a primary key. I wouldn't think that'd be a problem, but evidently it is. I've got my model name which is different from the table name, but I'm using `set_table_name` to specify the right one.

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feature_attributes
end

class FeatureAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'feature_attribute'
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

Once I load a feature that I know has related `feature_attributes` and call `feature.feature_attributes` on it, I get `nil`. Matter of fact, even `FeatureAttribute.first` gives me `nil`. The result of `FeatureAttribute.any?` returns `false`. I'm worried that ActiveRecord isn't reading any of the data from the table because there isn't a primary key. Is that what's going on here?

The `feature_attribute` table has the following columns.

```
feature_id
attribute_name
attribute_value
created_date
modified_date
```

Help!

*I'll also note that running the generated SQL directly against the MySQL server actually gets me the rows I want.*

```
SELECT `feature_attribute`.* FROM `feature_attribute` WHERE `feature_attribute`.`feature_id` = 24;
```

**EDIT**: I am so sorry. Next time I'll learn to check my `database.yml`. Evidently I was reading from a test database that had an identical feature table, but the `feature_attribute` table was totally empty.

I feel like a moron. Thanks for your help, everyone; I'm up voting you all for your troubles. I did like just about everybody's answer. (Can I down vote myself? :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to also set the primary key:

```
class FeatureAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'feature_attribute'
  set_primary_key 'feature_id'

  belongs_to :feature
end
```

**UPDATE**

I think your problem lies anywhere else. I just tested and ActiveRecords works fine with tables without a primary key:

For a simple table:

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things, :id => false do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

in console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
irb(main):001:0> Thing.create(:name=>'A name for the thing')
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `things` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2011-11-02 16:33:48', 'A name for the thing', '2011-11-02 16:33:48')
   (40.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Thing name: "A name for the thing", created_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48", updated_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48">
irb(main):002:0> Thing.first
  Thing Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `things`.* FROM `things` LIMIT 1
=> #<Thing name: "A name for the thing", created_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48", updated_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48">
irb(main):003:0>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Not very fine:

```
irb(main):003:0> Thing.create(:name=>'Another thing')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `things` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2011-11-02 16:40:59', 'Another thing', '2011-11-02 16:40:59')
   (35.4ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Thing name: "Another thing", created_at: "2011-11-02 16:40:59", updated_at: "2011-11-02 16:40:59">
irb(main):004:0> Thing.first
  Thing Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `things`.* FROM `things` LIMIT 1
=> #<Thing name: "A name for the thing", created_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48", updated_at: "2011-11-02 16:33:48">
irb(main):005:0> Thing.last
  Thing Load (11.8ms)  SELECT `things`.* FROM `things` ORDER BY `things`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'things.' in 'order clause': SELECT  `things`.* FROM `things`  ORDER BY `things`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'things.' in 'order clause': SELECT  `things`.* FROM `things`  ORDER BY `things`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not sure if you read well, but the table is called `FeatureAttribute`, and it `belongs_to :feature`, so the `feature_id` could never be the primary key.

Comment: `feature_id` actually belongs to `feature` and not `feature_attribute`… the actual `feature_attribute` table is without a primary key to speak of.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't read well. But what is the problem with adding a primary key to `feature_attributes` table then?

Comment: I just made a test. Read my UPDATE

Comment: Also read the UPDATE 2.) I would just add a primary key if I was you.

Comment: *"I think your problem lies anywhere else."* You're right; my table was totally empty after all (I was connected to a totally wrong database). You get the answer credit.

Answer (score 4):

If a certain attribute can occur only once for a feature, you assume `attribute_name` is the key, in combination with the `feature_id`. Rails does not support composite primary keys out of the box, but there is a gem called [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys) that supports just that.

In your model you can then write

```
set_primary_keys :feature_id, :attribute_name
```

If an attribute-name could occur multiple time for a single feature, the combination of `feature_id`, `attribute_name` and `attribute_value` is the key, and you should write

```
set_primary_keys :feature_id, :attribute_name, :attribute_value
```

Hope this helps.

[edit] Alternative approach:

The above clearly is not enough, so you could also do the following:

```
class Feature
  has_many :feature_attributes, :finder_sql => 'select * from feature_attributes where feature_id=\'#{id}\''
end
```

Hope that this does help :)

Comment: Aye, it would be a good idea, but unfortunately a few `attribute_name(s)` are repeated multiple times for several features, so it's not unique per feature.

Comment: Mmmm you are saying that the `attribute_name` is used for several features? So then the `feature_id` + `attribute_name` could be the key, right? Or, are you saying that the `attribute_name` occurs different times within a single feature, so then the `feature_id` + `attribute_name` + `attribute_value` should be the key, right? So why can't you use this?

Comment: Ah, I guess your second condition didn't process for me mentally; an attribute name can occur multiple times for a single feature, so I'll give the second option a shot. D'oh!

Comment: I looked at the SQL behind the attributes table in question, and sure enough, those three fields are listed as primary keys (`PRIMARY KEY  (feature_id,attribute_name,attribute_value`). I loaded composite_primary_keys and defined those three fields as primary keys, but no love. I still can't query a single row out of that table with ActiveRecord, related to a `feature` or by itself.

Comment: What queries does ActiveRecord generate? Maybe we can see some error there.

Comment: I've got the SQL that ActiveRecord generates at the end of my question above.

Comment: Using the `:finder_sql` statement above, when I run a query to grab a `Feature` throws a `NameError` because `id` cannot be found as a `Class` attribute.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. I still do believe the `composite_primary_keys` could be really useful for you. I hope you give it a try. Definitely if you will need to add new `FeatureAttribute's`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'legacy_table_name'
  self.primary_key = nil
end
```

Then query using `Feature.find_by field:'value'` or other ActiveRecord queries.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't possible to update the table to just add a autoincrement primary key, then you might be better served dealing with it manually:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  # get rid of has_many feature_attributes and use this instead
  def feature_attributes
    FeatureAttribute.find_by_sql(["select * from feature_attribute where feature_id = ?", self.id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code (by itself) throws an error as Rails can't locate the `find_by_sql` method on an instance of `Feature`. Appending `Feature` to the front allows it to be run, but it sill won't retrieve any results (same with replacing `Feature` with `FeatureAttribute`). The generated SQL looks fine, though: `select * from feature_attribute where feature_id = 24`

Comment: @BenjaminKreeger You are right, I'm sorry I forgot find_by_sql is class-level. You should use FeatureAttribute.find_by_sql because then the array handed back with be of FeatureAttribute objects that way, with access to methods of that class.