# Replacing rails convensions (database table names & fields)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, associations, activeadmin

**Hello,**
I am trying to create new rails application using active_admin.
But Table names & column names are not as per naming convention
Here i am having two model which are having one to one association.
In SUIUBI table there is no id column instead there is UBIREFNUM column
and in SUIURA table URAUBIREFNUM column is foreign key instead of suiubi_id column 
So it gives error

```
undefined method `suiubi_id_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Suiura:0x007ff50ca1fe38>
```

For that I have used foreign key directly in association.
But it wont help & still gives error .

> class Suiubi < ActiveRecord::Base
>   set_table_name "SUIUBI"
>
> attr_accessible :UBIREFNUM, :UBIFNAME, :UBILNAME, :UBIEMAILID, :UBIMOBNUM, :UBITELNUM, :UBICITY, :UBIADD, :UBIDEPT, :UBIPASSWORD, :UBICREATEDDATE,
>      :UBICREATEDBY, :UBIMODIFIEDDATE, :UBIMODIFIEDBY, :UBIISACTIVE
>
> has_one :sui_ura
>   end
>
> class Suiura < ActiveRecord::Base
>   set_table_name "SUIURA"
>    attr_accessible :URANAME, :URAUBIREFNUM, :URARMTREFNUM, :URAISACTIVE, :URACREATEDDATE, :URACREATEDBY, :URAMODIFIEDDATE, :URAMODIFIEDBY
>
> belongs_to :suiubi, :primary_key => "UBIREFNUM", :foreign_key => "URAUBIREFNUM"
>   end

I know the error is due to the table name and column names
But I need the database in strictly this way
So how can I associate the two model?

Answer (score 0):

You need specify the id and/or foreign key attribute to Active Records...

take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

And there is a similar question with a great answer here too

[Rails ActiveRecord: legacy table without primary key shows nil for result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973335/rails-activerecord-legacy-table-without-primary-key-shows-nil-for-result)

regards,